# How do I distinguish between a DirectoryEntry Invalid path, or not being able to connect to LDAP in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

Let's say I have this LDAP path and I want to search for an object in AD using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry:

```
 var path = "LDAP://test.com/CN=bob,OU=Users,DC=test,DC=com"
```

This path was retrieved from AD 1 minute ago. What if the object was deleted that second or the connection to Active Directory dropped. 
In my application, i stored this path, and I want to change one of the attributes of that object. So, I retrieve the path and do whatever I want. In both cases, deleted object or no connection, I get the same Exception

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"
```

I want to throw an exception stating the problem, how do I distinguish between both cases? 
I want to do this because, in case it was a connection problem, i want to try again after a specific amount of time. However if the object is deleted, I want my Application user to know this.

DirectoryEntry Constructor does not do any kind of validation. In Addition, DirectoryEntry.Exsist(path) returns false, but does not give additional information. 
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with catching another exception, then throwing another:

```
try {
   my_dangerous_call();
} catch(COMException e) {
   throw new MyCustomException();
}
```

Comment: I understand that, But how do I know what is the deal here. does the object no longer exsist, or it was an error when connecting to AD?

Comment: What do you mean by deleted object? As in it was set to `null`?

Comment: No, I wish it returns null. This path reference a user in Active Directory in this case, Bob. LDAP://test.com/CN=bob,OU=Users,DC=test,DC=com....

Deleted object means no longer exists in Active Directory! 
Do i make sense?

Comment: What I mean Is, in both cases, the same exception is thrown. How to distinguish between both cases

Comment: I would poll just before and see if your connection is still active; if it isn't then, it's that, if it is, then it must be a deleted object, right?

Comment: Genius idea, lemme try it and ask my boss!